# Android on touch show dialog

Tags: android, touch-event

i add a button at the bottom of the screen, when user touch the button, it will show a dialog.

what i want is when user touch event is action_up, will dismiss this dialog

```
   btn.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch(event.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                 if (dialog != null && !dialog.isShowing()) {
                    dialog.show();
                 }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if(dialog!= null && dialog.isShowing()){
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

i know that dialog is add to the top level view DecorView

when dialog is showing, it will cover other views

i test this code is worked, on touch event is still pass to the button ontouch method

on touch event is not interrupt by dialog, is that right?

why dialog cover view not interrupt the touch event?

Comment: Yes, you are right. The dialog will only dismiss when you lift your finger from the screen. But do not forget MotionEvent_ACTION_CANCEL.

Answer (score 0):

on touch event is not interrupt by dialog, is that right?
no that's wrong, dialog is canceled when touched outside the window's bounds.
why dialog cover view not interrupt the touch event?
dialog cover view and interrupt the touch event.
to test this try:

```
dialog.setCancelable(false);
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

take a look
[Dialog Class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html)